# How to add a string into an array list in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I try to add a string "hello" into an array list, and convert the array list back into a string array, but I get weird output like this: [Ljava.lang.String;@1f26ecd2. What's the problem with that?

```
String s="hello";
   ArrayList<String> base = new ArrayList<String>();
   int a=0;
   if(a==0)
   {
       base.add(s);
   }
        String[] get=base.toArray(new String[base.size()]);
        System.out.print(get);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a loop to cycle get array to print its element.
If you print directly the array of string, you get the objec codename

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print array values, use Arrays.toString()

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(get));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error.. change the last line of that code to

```
System.out.print(get[0]);
```